# Show that, for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the set of $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\le c$ is convex and show inverse does not hold

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis

> Let $f\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Show that, for all
>   $c\in\mathbb{R}$, the set of points $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\le c$ is
>   convex. Show that the inverse is false.

So I must show that for two points $x,y$ such that $f(x) \le c$ and $f(y)\le c$, we have $f((1-t)x+ty)\le c$, right? By convexity of $f$, we have that

$$f((1-t)x+ty) \le (1-t)f(x) + tf(y) = f(x)-tf(x)+tf(y) \le c-tc+tc = c$$

Now to show that the inverse is not true, I must show that if, for every $x\in X$ we have $f(x)\le c$, then $f$ not necessarily if convex, that is, there exists at least one function that is not convex but $f(x)\le c$ for all $x\in X$.

I can think of a bounded function, $\sin x \le 1$, such that a line between two strategically chosen points, the line crosses the function in the middle of those two points. Is this a valid choice?

Comment: only if you choose well the domain $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically correct, but you need to indicate a proper domain for $\sin(x)$. Let $X=[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Then $\sin(x)$ is in fact concave on $X$, but nevertheless it satisfies that $\{x\in X|\sin(x)\leq c\}$ is an interval (possibly empty) thus convex for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

This example can be generalized to any non-convex monotone function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, choosing a bounded function that is not convex and showing that two endpoints are valid while the midpoint is not is a good way to do what you are asking.  You cannot prove something is true with examples, but you only need one counter-example to prove something is false. In your case I think you are very close, however you have not quite chosen the correct example. For any value of $x$, $\sin(x) <= 1$ is going to be true, as the maximum value of $\sin(x)$ is $1$.  Instead, think about $\sin(x) < 0.5$, because $\sin(0)$ and $\sin(\pi)$ are on your function, but $\sin(\pi/2)$ is not.